# How to use rpc exports in Frida?

Tags: python, frida

I tried to use rpc.exports.dispose but it's not working.
Here is code I tried:

```
import frida
import sys

device = frida.get_local_device()
session = device.attach('simple')
script = session.create_script("""
    rpc.exports.dispose = function() {
        console.log('dispose');
    };
""")
script.load()
sys.stdin.read()
```

According to the [documentation](https://frida.re/docs/gadget/#script) dispose should be executed before the hooked process terminates or the script is unloaded.

I terminated "simple" process by several ways (click Ctrl+C, run "kill -9 ", run "kill ").
But i couldn't see dispose log. I am using Ubuntu.
Can you please let me know what is wrong in my code?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion relying on code that is executed in a process while it is terminating is a bad idea. Too many things can go wrong and the code is not executed.

A far better way is to register the `detached` handler on Python side:

```
def on_detached():
    print("on_detached")

def on_detached_with_reason(reason):
    print("on_detached_with_reason:", reason)

def on_detached_with_varargs(*args):
    print("on_detached_with_varargs:", args)

session = frida.attach("simple")
print("attached")
session.on('detached', on_detached)
session.on('detached', on_detached_with_reason)
session.on('detached', on_detached_with_varargs)
```

Comment: https://frida.re/news/2018/04/28/frida-10-8-released/
Can you please check "Flush-before-exit" on the link?
Is the dispose function just defined function that can be called from within python code?

Comment: @Boris Ok, I didn't know that dispose is supposed to be some special function. I have updated my question so that it may be helpful to you. In the Frida tracker are also some issues on the dispose method. Looks like the dispose system has some problems or is a bit difficult to use.